# How to calculate the one-sided limit function?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am new to calculus and am just starting to learn. I have the following problem and am confused about how to solve it. $\lim_{x \to \pi/2-} f(x)$ where $f(x)=(2x/\pi)^{\tan(x)}.$ I have learned about L'hoptils rule but am not sure how to apply it in this scenario. I would like the explanation simple because I am just starting out. Thanks.

Comment: Don’t undo edits that make your question more readable.

Comment: Also, in English, we call this the limit **of a** function, or sometimes a “function limit,” but not a “limit function.” That term means something else.

Comment: L’Hopital is useful for you if you take logarithms of $f$, find the limit of the logarithm - if it exists - and use the continuity of logarithm to retrieve the limit of $f$

Comment: Try substituting $y=\frac{\pi}2-x,$ so that $y\to0^+.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry, I did that by accident

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First notice that as is our limit is of the indeterminate form $1^\infty$. Perhaps as a hint, one might employ the inverse relationship between the logarithm and the exponential: $$y=e^{\ln y}.$$

In our case we have $$(2x/\pi)^{\tan x}=e^{(\tan x)\ln (2x/\pi)}$$ Where I did sneak in the use of a log rule.